# How to add onClick events in one loop and toggle class on corresponding elements in another loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a bit lost of how to click a button in one loop/map and toggle a class on a corresponding  which again is in another separate loop/map?

Here my code:

```
<div className={`menu-secondary-container ${data.secondary.layout} ${secondaryOpen ? 'open' : ''}`}>
    
    <ul className='menu-secondary'>
        {data.secondary.tertiaryMenu && data.secondary.tertiaryMenu.map((a, j) =>
            // For each button which is clicked within this loop/map
            <li key={j}>
                <button type='button' id={data.secondary.class+'-'+j}>
                    {a.title} 
                    <span className="arrow next"></span>
                </button>
            </li>
        )}
    </ul>

    {data.secondary.tertiaryMenu && data.secondary.tertiaryMenu.map((h, x) =>       
        // Toggle a open class on the corresponding ul within this loop
        <ul className={`menu-tertiary ${data.secondary.class+'-'+x}`}>
            <li className='title' key={x}>
                <button type='button'>
                    <span className="arrow prev"></span> 
                    {h.title}
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    )}
    
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to approach this issue... I've read a bit about useRef but I'm not sure if it is something I can use here. Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do your objects have IDs you could attach to each button in both areas? So you could get the element in question by its ID?

Comment: @Lynx242 - I've updated the code with the <button> having an ID and the <ul> having a class name that matches the buttons ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I still struggle a little why you mark the `ul`-tag with a class instead of an ID. Because if you marked it with an ID you could access it this way:

```
<button type='button' 
    id={data.secondary.class+'-'+j}
     onclick="toggle(\''data.secondary.class+'-'+j'\')">
    {a.title} 
    <span className="arrow next"></span>
</button>

 toggle = (id) => {   
     var element = document.getElementById(id);
    
     // do something with it
 }
```